# Динамическое построение Linq запроса

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Created {get;set;}
    public bool IsDeleted {get;set;}
}
```

Думаю данные свойства есть почти в каждой сущности, и довольно часто Возникает необходимость получить список за период, т.е. что то типа такого:

```
var start = new DateTime(2015, 11, 01);
var stop = new DateTime(2015, 11, 30);
var results = context.Entity.Where(x=>x.Created>=start&&x.Created<=stop).ToList()
```

но довольно часто таких *сущностей* несколько и плодить по сути однообразный код крайне не хочется, другой пример получить строки где какое то значение равно заданному, т.е. что то типа этого:

```
var arg = true;
var results = context.Entity.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted==arg).ToList();
```

и это встречается тоже довольно часто ну и т.д.

т.е. хочется что то типа этого:

```
var start = new DateTime(2015, 11, 01);
var stop = new DateTime(2015, 11, 30);
var results = context.Entity.Beetwen("Created",start,stop).ToList();


public static class BaseEntityExtensions
{
     //где field это имя поля по которому надо фильтровать записи
     public static IQueryable<BaseEntity> Beetwen(this IQueryable<BaseEntity> src, string field, DateTime start, DateTime stop)
        {
            //Здесь надеюсь пока неизвестная мне *магия*
        }
}
```

Помогите реализовать метод Beetwen

Comment: Что такое `field`?

Comment: @Vlad это имя поля по которому надо фильтровать

Comment: Когда в Вашей сущности поле `Created` переименуется во что-то другое компилятор не подскажет Вам, что код `context.Entity.Beetwen("Created",start,stop)` стал невалиден, а ошибку Вы получите только в процессе выполнения.

Comment: @ApInvent да я это понимаю, таким образом я хочу избавиться от множества однотипных запросов которые я привел в примере. а почему бы `Created` не выбираться из списка к примеру, который содержит заведомо правильные имена полей?!

Comment: @Bald56rus, в любом случае необходимо будет следить за актуальностью этого списка

Comment: @Bald56rus, вы только проверьте, что получилось, я не запускал, поэтому могут быть какие-нибудь недочеты :-) По аналогии можно собрать и второе ваше выражение с простым сравнением, просто использовать для этого соответствующий метод и Expression

Comment: @Bald56rus: Хм. А почему не работает просто `src.Where(x=>x.Created>=start&&x.Created<=stop)`? // А, вижу — у вас проверки по разному _полю_.

Comment: @VladD хочу сделать общий метод для некоторых типов запросов, таких как значения в периоде, с одинаковым значением какого то поля. в проекте есть несколько моделей у которых есть одинаковые смысловые поля, и для каждой сущности бывает необходимости фильтровать по этим полям, т.е. одинаковый код поэтому и решил сделать обобщенные методы

Comment: @Bald56rus: Понял. Тогда и правда, способа лучше чем принятый ответ на текущий момент нет.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535040(v=vs.90).aspx) метод для [`IQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx) принимает [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) поэтому его можно собрать самостоятельно

```
public static IQueryable<T> Beetwen<T>(this IQueryable<T> src, string field, DateTime start, DateTime stop) where T: BaseEntity
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)); // Param_0
    var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(p, field); //Param_0.field
    var startExpr = Expression.Constant(start);
    var stopExpr = Expression.Constant(stop);

    var firstCondition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(prop, startExpr); // Param_0.field >= start
    var secondCondition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(prop, stopExpr); // Param_0.field <= stop

    var fullExpression = Expression.AndAlso(firstCondition, secondCondition); // Param_0.field >= start && Param_0.field <= stop

    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(fullExpression,p); // Param_0 => Param_0.field >= start && Param_0.field <= stop

    return src.Where(func);
}
```

Методы которые использовались:

- [Expression.Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.parameter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Expression.PropertyOrField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.propertyorfield(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Expression.Constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb349084(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb347364(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Expression.LessThanOrEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300261(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Expression.AndAlso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.andalso(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Expression.Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb340145(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Альтернативным подходом может быть использование библиотеки DynamicLinq (есть в NuGet) в ней можно передавать в функции не Expression, а строку

```
src.Where(string.Format("{0} >= @0 && {0} <= @1", field), start, stop);
```

---

По мотивам ответа @Vlad, только используя уже переданное выражение

```
public static IQueryable<T> Beetwen<T>(this IQueryable<T> src, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> propertyExpression, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var fromCondition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(from));
    var toCondition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(to));

    return src.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(fromCondition, toCondition), propertyExpression.Parameters.First()));
}
```

в использовании: `var res = query.Beetwen(_ => _.Date, from, to);`

---

И еще вариант, но не такой интересный как предыдущие

```
public static IQueryable<T> Beetwen<T>(this IQueryable<T> src, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> propertyExpression, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    Expression<Func<DateTime, bool>> func = d => d >= from && d <= to;

    return src.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(func, propertyExpression.Body), propertyExpression.Parameters.First()));
}
```

в использовании: `var res = query.Beetwen(_ => _.Date, from, to);`

---

немного обобщенный вариант

```
public static IQueryable<T> Beetwen<T,U>(this IQueryable<T> src, Expression<Func<T, U>> propertyExpression, U from, U to)
{
    var fromCondition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(from));
    var toCondition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propertyExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(to));

    return src.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(fromCondition, toCondition), propertyExpression.Parameters.First()));
}
```

в использовании: `var res = query.Beetwen(_ => _.Date, from, to);`

Comment: Вот ещё статья по теме: http://habrahabr.ru/post/83169/

Comment: @VladD уж лучше MSDN смотреть - там куча примеров и описано какой метод, что делает

Comment: Это да, но ссылки на MSDN вы уже привели. :) Так что я в дополнение. Статья хороша тем, что объясняет мотивацию, нужность всей этой механики.

Comment: @VladD, ну с этой стороны да. Если б они еще там про то, как Expression в провайдерах используют, типа LinqToSql - было б еще интереснее :-)

Answer (score 5):

Я бы посоветовал использовать решение, которое поддается рефакторингу. И передавать в метод не имя свойства, а выражение.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Beetwen<T>(this IQueryable<T> src, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> propertyExpression, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var parameterExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var parameterizedPropertyExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpr, ((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member.Name);

    var fromCondition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(parameterizedPropertyExpr, Expression.Constant(from));
    var toCondition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(parameterizedPropertyExpr, Expression.Constant(to));

    return src.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(fromCondition, toCondition), parameterExpr));
}
```

В этом случае метод можно вызывать вот так:

```
var res = query.Beetwen(_ => _.Date, from, to);
```

Comment: _.Date это так сказать свойство по которому будет осуществляться фильтрация? я так и не разобрался в `Func<>`

Comment: Да. Это свойство сущности, по которому нужно фильтровать.

Comment: Это нужно попробовать, он может ругнуться на то что в MemberExpression используется не тот parameterExpression. Причем ругнуться только во время выполнения

Comment: а, увидел, что MemberExpression только для получения имени свойства используется :-)

Comment: Я бы ещё убрал из функции `IQueryable` и оставил лишь динамическое построение `Expresssion<Func<T, bool>>` из `Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>` и двух дат.

Comment: @VladD, а зачем? Какой use case у такого метода?

Comment: Например, из него можно строить ещё более сложный Expression, и лишь в самом конце применять его к `IQueryable`. Ну и можно тогда использовать не только с `Where`, но и с `TakeWhile`, например.

Comment: @VladD, его тогда и обзывать надо по другому, сейчас-то конкретное название и ясно что делает метод

Comment: @Grundy: `ConstructBetweenExpression`? (_P. S.: вроде ж правильно between?_)

Comment: @VladD, ага `between`, а название скорее какое-нибудь `RangeExpression` или `GetRangeExpression` и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy, Если называть Range, то не очень хорошо привязываться к DateTime. Да, between. Топикстартер нас запутал :)

Comment: @Vlad, в идеале от `DateTime` тоже надо уйти, будет просто проверка чего-то в диапазоне значений, по сути не важно `DateTime` это или `int` и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy: С этим будет сложнее, т. к. `<` не протягивается через дженерики.

Comment: @VladD, но мы же не используем напрямую `>` или `<` ;-) а в Expressions можно передать любой тип, главное чтобы в нем этот оператор был перегружен

Comment: @Grundy: Хм :) Убедили.

Comment: @Grundy как много хороших мыслей со всеми замечаниями согласен. У меня тоже возникла идея что параметры должны быть такого же типа что и фильтруемое поле. Вот только как это сделать если это возможно пока не знаю:)

Comment: @Bald56rus очень просто на самом деле, если использовать вариант с передачей Expression а не строки

Comment: @Bald56rus, обновил свой ответ