# Определение свойства, по которому нужно произвести фильтр

Tags: c#, запрос, рефлексия

Здравствуйте. Возник очень тяжелый вопрос с которым я никогда не сталкивался. мне нужно создать метод, который поймет по какому свойству нужно сделать фильтр. Т.е., допустим у меня есть класс

```
public class User {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Nick {get; set;}
}
```

И мне нужно вытащить из базы некоторых пользователей но критерий заранее не известен, в запросе Name или Nick могут быть null.

В данный момент это выглядит примерно так:

```
//это часть когда находится в классе user
IQarable<User> query ... тут создается query и передается в метод ниже
...

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
                query = query.Where(x => x.VenueName.Contains(Venue));
        }

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nick))
        {
                query = query.Where(x => x.City.Contains(City));

        } //и так далее
```

Внутри блоков If есть еще кое какая проверка, вот поэтому я пытаюсь это вынести в 1 метод, но не в этом суть.

Я пытаюсь сделать метод, который принимает query и свойство в виде строки, по которому нужно выполнить Where(...), что бы это выглядело так

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
                query = SearchMethod(query, "Name", "Jhon");
        }
```

Я не могу представить как мне заменить выражение `Where(x => x./*тут свойство, которое каким-то образом определено*/.Contais("SearchingValue"))` что-то другое, что может вычислить свойство по которому я веду поиск, и подставить его в это выражение. По рефлексии я смог получить только само свойство.

```
Type t = this.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("EventName");
```

Прошу вашей помощи в решении этой проблемы.

Comment: А почему вы хотите передавать имя свойства именно как строку? Почему не в виде лямбда-выражения?

Comment: для получения значения из PropertyInfo можно воспользоваться методом GetValue: `prop.GetValue(this)`.

Comment: @Grundy так значение свойства я передаю в метод, спасибо, кстати я думал, почему у меня exeption вылетал когда я писал prop.GetValue(prop)

Comment: @VladD мне бы хоть как его передавать, просто показалось, что работать со строкой будет легче всего

Comment: nameof лучше строк

Comment: @VladD вы имеете ввиду что-то вроде этого? `SearchMethod(query, x => x.Name, "Jhon");` тогда в аргументах можно заменить string на `Func<User, string> selector`, я так понимаю

Comment: А что насчёт `x => x.Name == "Jhon"`? И не `Func<User, bool>`, а `Expression<Func<User, bool>>`. Иначе ваше `IQueryable` превратится в `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @VladD я понял вас, но я не работал с Expression, мне показали то что вы представили, но я понятия не имею как это развить

Comment: @VladD тут еще дело в том, что есть условие, я думал оно не будет иметь в этом вопросе значения, но видимо... строка может прийти со звездочкой вначале, например, "*Jhon", это значит, что я должен искать не Contains, а StartWith, поэтому сразу условие так не передать, и в методе мне и нужно выполнить эту проверку, есть ли звездочка или нет и от этого зависит, что я верну

Comment: Получается мне придется передавать в метод 2 лямбды, 1 для contains другая для startwith, и еще придется передавать флаг, который будет отражать наличие звездочки в поисковой строке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамическое построение Linq запроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467598/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-linq-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отфильтровать `IQueryable` по `Func<T, bool>` нельзя. (У вас получится `IEnumerable`.) Для сохранения `IQueryable` вам придётся строить `Expression` (и кажется, вручную). Вот [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx).

Для вашего случая, если нужно сравнивать значение с константой, можно сделать так (не тестировал, возможны вылеты в рантайме):

```
IQueryable<T> Filter<T, V>(IQueryable<T> original, Expression<Func<T, V>> еxtractor, V value)
{
    return original.Where(ProjectionEquals(еxtractor, value));
}

Expression<Func<T, bool>> ProjectionEquals<T, V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> еxtractor, V value)
{
    var body = Expression.Equal(еxtractor.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, еxtractor.Parameters[0]);
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
query = Filter(query, x => x.Name, "Jhon");
```

Внутри `Filter` можно накрутить, понятно, более сложную логику.

---

Если всё же очень хочется потерять проверки на этапе компиляции и передавать имена свойств как строки, можно так:

```
IQueryable<T> Filter<T, V>(IQueryable<T> original, string propName, V value)
{
    return original.Where(PropertyEquals<T, V>(propName, value));
}

Expression<Func<T, bool>> PropertyEquals<T, V>(string propName, V value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var left = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propName);
    var body = Expression.Equal(left, Expression.Constant(value));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```

и пользоваться так:

```
query = Filter(query, "Name", "Jhon");
```

Понятна схема?

---

Для примера, если вам нужно `Contains`:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetContains<T>(string propName, string value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var prop = Expression.Property(parameter, propName);
    var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var valueAsExpr = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var contains = Expression.Call(propOrField, containsMethod, valueAsExpr);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(contains, parameter);
}
```

---

Как подсказывает в комментарии @Pavel Mayorov, последнюю функцию можно переписать проще:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetContains<T>(string propName, string value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var prop = Expression.Property(parameter, propName);
    var valueAsExpr = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var contains = Expression.Call(prop, "Contains", null, valueAsExpr);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(contains, parameter);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, попробую разобраться в вашей схеме. Мне еще друг помог с этим вопросом, у него тоже получилос. вроде бы похоже на ваш случай, но все же, сейчас сброшу этот вариант в ответы тоже

Comment: `PropertyOrField` избыточно - все известные мне ORM не умеют работать с полями.

Comment: `containsMethod` также не нужно получать явно - `Expression.Call` умеет сам искать метод по имени: `Expression.Call(prop, "Contains", null, valueAsExpr)`

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, насчёт полей это да. Но лучше показать избыточную функциональность, чем недостаточную.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А насчёт `Expression.Call` не знал. Я всё искал метод не конструировать лямбды вручную, а задать как-нибудь наподобие `return t => extractor(t).Contains(value)` для `Expression`'а `extractor`. Но так, судя по всему, невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Исходный код у меня получился такой

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EventName))
        {
            query = query.ContainsOrStartWithQuery(x => x.EventName, EventName);               
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Venue))
        {
            query = query.ContainsOrStartWithQuery(x => x.VenueName, Venue);
        }
```

Сам метод находится в статическом классе, он получился довольно большим.

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    #region EgorAdded
    private static MethodInfo containsMethod;
    private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod; 
    static ExpressionHelper()
    {
        containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1);
        startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "StartsWith" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddContains<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string value)
    {
        var body = selector.GetBody().AsString();
        var x = Expression.Call(body, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(value));

        LambdaExpression e = Expression.Lambda(x, selector.Parameters.ToArray());
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)e;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AddStartsWith<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string value)
    {
        var body = selector.GetBody().AsString();
        var x = Expression.Call(body, startsWithMethod, Expression.Constant(value));

        LambdaExpression e = Expression.Lambda(x, selector.Parameters.ToArray());
        return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)e;
    }

    private static Expression GetBody(this LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        Expression body;
        if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
            body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
        else
            body = expression.Body;

        return body;
    }

    private static Expression AsString(this Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression.Type == typeof(string))
            return expression;

        MethodInfo toString = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "StringConvert" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1 && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(double?));
        var cast = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(double?));
        return Expression.Call(toString, cast);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> ContainsOrStartWithQuery<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> selector, string search)
    {
        if (search.StartsWith("*"))
        {
            search = search.Substring(1);
            query = query.Where(selector.AddContains<TEntity>(search));
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.Where(selector.AddStartsWith<TEntity>(search));
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460057/call-contains-method-in-linq-to-entities-expression-on-a-type-other-than-strin Руководствовался этим вопросом

Comment: Ваши `.ToArray()` избыточны - есть перегрузки, которые принимают перечисление.