# linq .Select(q => new { набор полей по условию })

Tags: c#, linq

Как создать динамический объект в .Select... ?
*[другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467598) - не является моим случаем...*

точнее меня интересует примерно следующее:

```
var RezultForGrid = RezultListCars.Select(cars => new
{
    CarId = cars.Id,
    cPhoto = dc.CarPhotos.Where(p => p.Car_CarPhoto == cars.Id).Select(o => o.Id).Count(), 
    Preselling = cars.PresellingStatus,
    EnginePower = cars.EnginePower.Value,
    Transmission = cars.Transmission,
    CabinType = cars.CabinType,
    CabinColor = cars.CabinColor,
    PurchaseManager = cars.PurchaseManager,
    PresentSale = (dc.SaleOrders.Count(p => p.Car.Id == cars.Id && (p.Status != "Отказ" && p.Status != null)) > 0 ? true : false),                             InSaleDate = cars.InSaleDate.Value
});
```

всё ясно всё понятно, но к примеру мне заранее известно что поля CarId, cPhoto и ряд других мне не нужны... а к примеру нужно всего два поля... CabinType и CabinColor...
но о том нужны они или нет я могу узнать к примеру по условию...

```
string FieldsList = "CabinType|CabinColor|";
// тогда если можно было бы написать ->
if (FieldsList.Contains("CabinType"))
    CabinType = cars.CabinType,
```

но так не напишешь... как быть?

**дополнение**

спасибо [klutch1991](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195735/klutch1991) за представленный ответ.
Но бьюсь с продолжением...
в отладчике если посмотреть к примеру `RezultForGrid[0].CarId` то выдаётся значение всё вроде бы понятно... т.е. если бы использовался `List<_ЗаранееИзвестнаяСтруктура_>` то отладчик бы показал тоже самое...
ОК...
Но ранее основываясь всё на том же списке "желаемых к выводу" полей я определяю столбцы грида и назначаю `DataProprtyName`, но в результате на гриде я ничего не вижу... хотя по количеству строк грид совпадает...
я делаю так:

```
 foreach (FieldListItem _f in _fields.ShownList.Items)
 {
     if (_f.Value == "id")
     {
         DataGridViewTextBoxColumn _col_id = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
         _col_id.HeaderText = _f.Text;
         _col_id.Name = "Column_CarId";
         CarsGrid.Columns.Add(_col_id);
         CarsGrid.Columns["Column_CarId"].DataPropertyName = "CarId";
     }
     else if (_f.Value == "PhotoCount")
     {
         DataGridViewImageColumn _col_photo = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
         _col_photo.HeaderText = _f.Text;
         _col_photo.Name = "PhotoCountColumn";
         CarsGrid.Columns.Add(_col_photo);
         CarsGrid.Columns["PhotoCountColumn"].DataPropertyName = "cPhoto";
     }
 }
// здесь код который собирает List<dynamic>
// Ну и после этого всего команда:
CarsGrid.DataSource = RezultForGrid;
```

грид пол количеству строк соответствует `RezultForGrid.Count()` но все ячейки пустые...
опять таки вопрос - **что я делаю не так?**

Comment: а почему вы не хотите сделать `FieldsList` типа `List<string>`, либо просто массивом из строк? В вашем случае можно сделать сплит, а затем уже Contains.

Comment: Используйте тернарный оператор. Ненужные свойства анонимного объекта зануляйте, либо устанавливайте дефолтные значения в случае, если они не содержатся в `FieldsList`.

Comment: так я хочу иметь элемент без лишних свойств... и все свойства у меня именуются дабы в последствии привязать RezultForGrid (CarsGrid.DataSource = RezultForGrid; CarsGrid.Columns["Column_CabinType"].DataPropertyName = "CabinType";)

Comment: FieldsList я беру из sql там хранится перечень полей которые захотел увидеть в результате юзер

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамическое построение Linq запроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467598/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-linq-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# - язык со строгой типизацией, но в случае необходимости, позволяет использовать динамическую типизацию. Для этого в C# есть тип `dynamic`. В вашем кокретном случае код для получения коллекции динамически типизированных элементов будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var RezultForGrid = new List<dynamic>();

RezultListCars.ToList().ForEach(car => {
     dynamic dynamicObject = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
     if (FieldsList.Contains("CabinType")) dynamicObject.CabinType = car.CabinType;
     //и так для каждого поля
     RezultForGrid.Add(dynamicObject);
});
```

В результате в переменной `RezultForGrid` будут храниться нужные Вам объекты с нужным количеством полей, однако при таком подходе вы не сможете использовать IntelliSense на объектах коллекции. В общем случае трудно, конечно, представить такую ситуацию, когда это нужно, но, как говорится, хозяин-барин:)

Comment: просто шикарно, то что нужно! НО :) вопрос... я получил RezultForGrid и теперь могу сделать CarsGrid.DataSource = RezultForGrid; но судя по всему добавляя динамически столбцы в зависимости от необходимости я так ощущаю что как-то неверно присваиваю CarsGrid.Columns["Column_CabinColor"].DataPropertyName = "CabinColor"; подскажите как правильно прописать DataPropertyName для свойства данного динамического объекта?... Спасибо.

Comment: хотелось бы прокомментировать _"трудно представить ситуацию когда это нужно"_. Задача примерно следующая вывод склада автомобилей из базы... при этом есть юзеры с разными правами и "цели" у пользователей разные... воротить несколько одинаковых форм под каждую роль с разным набором столбцов глупо... поэтому есть кнопка по которой открывается форма выбора интересующих к выводу полей... юзер выбирает те поля таблицы что хочет видеть... и основываясь на выбранных полях я строю результирующую таблицу...

Comment: понятно что можно было бы использовать видимость столбцов, но зачем насиловать базу вычеслениями знчений столбцов и их затем прятать если они не нужны как класс вообще... поэтому и хотелось получать дианмический объект с теми свойствами какие нужны... сформировать список этих объектов (есть ещё фильтр по марке/модели и прочее и прочее)... и вывести их на грид... очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, т.к. уже столько пройдено и чувствуется что искомый результат совсем рядом...

Comment: склад атомобилей из базы - это не одна таблица... а целый набор из связанных и связанных со связанными таблиц... таблица с фотографиями, обращения по автомобилям (несвязанный объект по сути но в анкете обращения есть случаи когда указывается конкретный искомый id), есть стадии предпродажной подготовки (и в один из столбцов надо вывести комментарий одного из события предпродажки)... вобщем итоговая максимальная строка грида (если пользователем выбраны все поля к выводу) шерстит много разных таблиц... и я не хочу лишний раз дёргать эти таблицы если они не нужны... HELP!!!