# Связывание List<dynamic> с DataGridView (столбцы добавлены ранее в коде)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, dynamic

Прошу прощения за отдельную тему, но [предыдущая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651855/linq-selectq-new-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E) уже без реакции + второй вопрос всё-таки это отдельная тема не связанная с изначальным вопросом [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651855/linq-selectq-new-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E).

Итак я имею `List<dynamic>` построенный следующим образом

```
    var RezultForGrid = new List<dynamic>();
    RezultListCars.ToList().ForEach(car => {
        dynamic dynamicObject = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        if (FieldsList.Contains("CabinType")) dynamicObject.CabinType = car.CabinType;
        //и так для каждого поля
        RezultForGrid.Add(dynamicObject);
   });
```

Спасибо [klutch1991](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195735/klutch1991) за [представленный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651855/linq-selectq-new-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E).
Но бьюсь с продолжением...
в отладчике если посмотреть к примеру `RezultForGrid[0].CarId` то выдаётся значение всё вроде бы понятно... т.е. если бы использовался `List<_ЗаранееИзвестнаяСтруктура_>` то отладчик бы показал тоже самое...
ОК...
Но ранее основываясь всё на том же списке "желаемых к выводу" полей я определяю столбцы грида и назначаю `DataProprtyName`, но в результате на гриде я ничего не вижу (`CarsGrid.DataSource = RezultForGrid;`)... хотя по количеству строк грид совпадает...
я делаю так:

```
 foreach (FieldListItem _f in _fields.ShownList.Items)
 {
     if (_f.Value == "id")
     {
         DataGridViewTextBoxColumn _col_id = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
         _col_id.HeaderText = _f.Text;
         _col_id.Name = "Column_CarId";
         CarsGrid.Columns.Add(_col_id);
         CarsGrid.Columns["Column_CarId"].DataPropertyName = "CarId";
     }
     else if (_f.Value == "PhotoCount")
     {
         DataGridViewImageColumn _col_photo = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
         _col_photo.HeaderText = _f.Text;
         _col_photo.Name = "PhotoCountColumn";
         CarsGrid.Columns.Add(_col_photo);
         CarsGrid.Columns["PhotoCountColumn"].DataPropertyName = "cPhoto";
     }
 }
// здесь код который собирает List<dynamic>
// Ну и после этого всего команда:
CarsGrid.DataSource = RezultForGrid;
```

грид пол количеству строк соответствует `RezultForGrid.Count()` но все ячейки пустые...
опять таки вопрос - **что я делаю не так?**
что надо прописать в `.DataPropertyName` для каждой колонки чтобы каждая колонка знала с каким полем динамического объекта она связана?

Comment: "Терзают меня смутные сомненья"(с) что это корректное поведение. dynamic предназначен для получения неопознанных объектов извне и только. Для внутреннего пользования, а уж тем более reflection, он ни как не подходит, поскольку там может оказаться все что угодно, например нативный COM компонент, у которого просто нет нужных метаданных для reflection. Хотя могу и ошибаться.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте klutch1991 пригласил бы в чат и обсудил бы(раз он не отвечает). А если бы у меня была такая задача, я бы сделал класс, который вмещает в себя все возможные поля, а в представлении подтягивал то, что нужно.

Идея сделать подобное - достойна уважения, но C# - строго типизированный язык. Динамика добавлена далеко не для этого(и то не такая уж там динамика)(в документации хорошо про это пишут). Подобные навороты хорошо работают в python + Qt.

По вашей теме: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic

Посмотрите, как работают с API автоматизации Office + WPF. Уверен наткнетесь на решения.